# Running the same code in three different fragments under the common class

Tags: java, android, generics, android-databinding

I am using databinding in my application.
I have three different fragments, all three have toolbars with the same id.
I have code that is the same in three toolbars.

```
        float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius); //32dp
        MaterialShapeDrawable materialShapeDrawable = (MaterialShapeDrawable) binding.toolbar.getBackground();
        materialShapeDrawable.setShapeAppearanceModel(materialShapeDrawable.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build());
```

I want to create a common class as below and run the same code from here, but I couldn't figure out how to transfer the binding structure.

```
public class MenuFragmentsToolbar<T> {

    public void applyRadiusCorner(T binding){

        float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius); //32dp
        MaterialShapeDrawable materialShapeDrawable = (MaterialShapeDrawable) binding.toolbar.getBackground();
        materialShapeDrawable.setShapeAppearanceModel(materialShapeDrawable.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
                .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just pass in the `View` or `MaterialShapeDrawable` instead of the binding?

```
public static void applyRadiusCorner(View v) {
   if(!(v.getBackground() instanceof MaterialShapeDrawable)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   applyRadiusCorner((MaterialShapeDrawable) v.getBackground());
}

public static void applyRadiusCorner(MaterialShapeDrawable drawable) {
  final float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
  drawable.setShapeAppearanceModel(drawable.getShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(ROUNDED,radius)
    .build());
}
```

And use it as `applyRadiusCorner(binding.toolbar)`.

**Edit:**

Wrapping this in a class:

```
class StyleableToolbar {

  private final Toolbar;
  private final MaterialShapeDrawable background;
  private final Resources res;
  
  private StyleableToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {
     this.toolbar = toolbar;
     this.background = (MaterialShapeDrawable) toolbar.getBackground();
     this.res = toolbar.getResources();
  }
 
  static Optional<StyleableToolbar> from(Toolbar toolbar) {
    return (toolbar.getBackground() instanceof MaterialShapeDrawable) 
      ? Optional.of(new StyleableToolbar(toolbar)) 
      : Optional.empty()
  }

  void applyRadiusCorner() {
    final float radius = res.getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius); 
    final ShapeAppearanceModel sam = background
      .getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setAllCorners(ROUNDED,radius)
      .build();
    background.setShapeAppearanceModel(sam);
  }

}
```

With usage `StyleableToolbar.from(binding.toolbar).ifPresent(StyleableToolbar::applyRadiusCorner);`

Comment: Thanks, this method worked. My approach was wrong, now I understand it, I was always trying to access the binding inside the class, I didn't think to send it directly from outside.

Comment: That's good, I did add an example too of how you could create a class for this